# chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener deprecated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a [google chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows):

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function callback)
```

[image: first]

Deprecated javascript symbol - WHERE?

[image: same]

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(){});
```

Comment: Please use text-wise errors and paste them here as code, don't use external screenshot links. It's easier for folks here to help you if you have all the information in one place. 
and please make a good problem statement so that the community can get to the point without having to assume/ask you things for clarifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is shown by your IDE because it doesn't know about `chrome` API and it thinks you're using the deprecated DOM method [MediaQueryList.addListener](https://devdocs.io/dom/mediaquerylist/addlistener).

The solution is to install [DefinitelyTyped @types/chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome) library in your IDE.
If you need an instruction, google up e.g. "how to load definitelytyped in vscode".